# Adding Multiple YouTube Posts in WordPress

Tags: youtube, wordpress.com

Recently I started a WordPress site to share my music creations which I have already uploaded to YouTube. So I added them one by one as Posts, but when I play them, all the Posts plays the same track that I uploaded last. What's wrong with this? Can any one suggest me a fix?

[Wizard Of Music](http://wizardofmusic.wordpress.com)

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: http://wizardofmusic.wordpress.com

Comment: When you embedded these did you use the YouTube iframe code?

Comment: No, I just inserted the url which I taken from "Share" in youtube video

Comment: Any specific reason you can't use YouTube provided HTML directly in your post?

Comment: It's working with iFrame embedded code, Thanx Matthew!

Comment: Good stuff. Have fun :) Might want to list the question as answered just in case anyone else needs the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use YouTube embedded iframe through their share feature listed under the video and copy it into your post as HTML. This was answered through comments to the original post, but for anyone requiring a full answer.

Visit your YouTube video and click on "Share" below the video.

[image]

Next click "Embed" to get your HTML code.

[image]

Copy the iframe code it provides and paste it into your WordPress post to embed your YouTube video.

[image]